# force file creation/writing before the end of the test

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I have the following code in a test:

```
@Test
void genericTest() {
    //stuff
    createTempJsonFile(filename, body);
    func.method(filename);
    //stuff
}

private void createTempJsonFile(String filename, String body) {
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write(body);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          //stuff
        }
    }
```

The file is correctly created. The problem is that `func.method` does not find it, indeed Intellij only shows me the file created (appearing in the file list) at the end of the execution of the test.

The issue is not the file path because on the further executions (when the file already exists since it was created at the end of the previous one), the test regularly passes.

To me, it looks like the file creation is finalized only at the end of the test and that would be unacceptable since I need to operate in it in the test itself.

How can I fix it? Is there a way to make the `func.method` wait until the file is generated?

Comment: Try using Thread.sleep() to wait awhile until the file gets created(eg. Thread.sleep(3000)).

Comment: I've tried putting up to Thread.sleep(20000) with no success.

Comment: If you require to set up a file to run your test why don't you try calling it in a @BeforeMethod annotation instead of in your test? Is it required that that method be in your test?

Comment: The content of the file depends on some data calculated at the beginning of the test itself

Comment: I think the problem must be in your func.method() itself, can you display the method?

Comment: It's a method of an internal library in my company which read the file using a Java InputStream

Comment: Try running the `createTempJsonFile()` method in a separate thread and waiting in the main thread.

Comment: what progress have you made on this?